# jquery datatables, table unavailable after modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm building a asp.net mvc application that uses the datatables grid. I display the grid. On the grid I added a rowclick event:

```
function CreateRowClickHandler() {
var table = $('#table').dataTable();
$("#table > tbody").on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var index = $('#table').data('id-index');
    var id = table.fnGetData($(this)[0])[index];

    var url = $('#table').data('rowclick-url');
    url += "/" + id;
    $().loadPartial(url);

  });

}
```

The loadpartial function loads the mvc action:

```
 $.fn.loadPartial = function (url, callback) {
    var container = ($(this).length == 0) ? ($("#jqcontainer")) : ($(this));
    container.load(url, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 403) {
            $('body').notifyBox({
                message: 'Unauthorized access! Call support for help!'
            });
        }
        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
            $('body').notifyBox({
                message: 'The process failed for unknown reasons! Call support for help!'
            });
        }
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest);
    });
};
```

When I go into the chrome debugger, when I first load the page I can call:

```
  $('#table').dataTable().fnReloadAjax();
```

This can be repeated as many times as I want. It reloadds the data from the server. When I clicked on one of the rows, and after I closed the modal window with the code below:

```
                    $('#partialview').dialog("close");
```

In the chrome debugger the fnreloadajax gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fnReloadAjax'
```

It looks like the object is no DataTables grid anymore after the model window is closed, but I cannot figure out why this happens. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: are you reloading jquery in the page which you are loading via the .load() function?

Comment: it is a normal mvc page, so probably yes... lets see if checking that would do the trick..

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed that I returned the View instead of a partial.

Answer (score 0):

I returned the complete page. This resulted in a fresh copy of jquery that was loaded. Wirey helped me figure this out. After returning only a partial view from the controller the problem was solved.